# To disabled the `PrintLastLog` on the SSH server

Tags: ssh, openssh

1. I can connect by ssh, and preform commands normally.
2. I can only login successfully connecting by WCP. But after the login it gives this error:

[image]

```
Error detecting variable containing return code of last command.
```

I searched it, and it said I need to disabled the `PrintLastLog` on the server. Then I disabled it, restarted the service, I restarted the VPS by OpenVZ on Ubuntu 16.

But it keeps showing the login message:

```
Last login: Sun Jan  8 08:06:13 2017 from XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX
entered into XXX XXXX
```

and I am still not connecting with WCP.

This is my `vim /etc/ssh/sshd_config` file:

```
# Package generated configuration file
# See the sshd_config(5) manpage for details

# What ports, IPs and protocols we listen for
Port 22
# Use these options to restrict which interfaces/protocols sshd will bind to
#ListenAddress ::
#ListenAddress 0.0.0.0
Protocol 2
# HostKeys for protocol version 2
HostKey /etc/ssh/ssh_host_rsa_key
HostKey /etc/ssh/ssh_host_dsa_key
HostKey /etc/ssh/ssh_host_ecdsa_key
HostKey /etc/ssh/ssh_host_ed25519_key
#Privilege Separation is turned on for security
UsePrivilegeSeparation no

# Lifetime and size of ephemeral version 1 server key
KeyRegenerationInterval 3600
ServerKeyBits 1024

# Logging
SyslogFacility AUTH
LogLevel INFO


# Authentication:
LoginGraceTime 120
PermitRootLogin yes
StrictModes yes

RSAAuthentication yes
PubkeyAuthentication yes
#AuthorizedKeysFile     %h/.ssh/authorized_keys

# Don't read the user's ~/.rhosts and ~/.shosts files
IgnoreRhosts no
# For this to work you will also need host keys in /etc/ssh_known_hosts
RhostsRSAAuthentication no
# similar for protocol version 2
HostbasedAuthentication no
# Uncomment if you don't trust ~/.ssh/known_hosts for RhostsRSAAuthentication
#IgnoreUserKnownHosts yes

# To enable empty passwords, change to yes (NOT RECOMMENDED)
PermitEmptyPasswords no

# Change to yes to enable challenge-response passwords (beware issues with
# some PAM modules and threads)
ChallengeResponseAuthentication no

# Change to no to disable tunnelled clear text passwords
PasswordAuthentication yes

# Kerberos options
#KerberosAuthentication no
#KerberosGetAFSToken no
#KerberosOrLocalPasswd yes
#KerberosTicketCleanup yes


# GSSAPI options
#GSSAPIAuthentication no
#GSSAPICleanupCredentials yes

X11Forwarding yes
X11DisplayOffset 10
PrintMotd no
PrintLastLog no
TCPKeepAlive yes
UseLogin no

#MaxStartups 10:30:60
#Banner /etc/issue.net

# Allow client to pass locale environment variables
AcceptEnv LANG LC_*

Subsystem sftp /usr/lib/openssh/sftp-server

# Set this to 'yes' to enable PAM authentication, account processing,
# and session processing. If this is enabled, PAM authentication will
# be allowed through the ChallengeResponseAuthentication and
# PasswordAuthentication.  Depending on your PAM configuration,
# PAM authentication via ChallengeResponseAuthentication may bypass
# the setting of "PermitRootLogin without-password".
# If you just want the PAM account and session checks to run without
# PAM authentication, then enable this but set PasswordAuthentication
# and ChallengeResponseAuthentication to 'no'.
UsePAM yes
```

Comment: What errors do you see in error log on the server? Do you have `openssh-sftp-server` installed (which is used by WinSCP regardless the name). The last login is printed by PAM these days.

Comment: I just installed this `openssh-sftp-server`, and set the PAM to `no`. I restarted the ssh service by `sudo /etc/init.d/ssh restart`. I and it keep showing. Then I did `reboot`, and after the reboot, it was the same. I connect using a user non-existent on the machine using what they call `Emergency SSH Connection`. Its password changes every time I reboot, and once I am logged on, I am the user root, and it is the only user existent.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are trying to connect to the wrong machine. See, your VPS service is providing 2 IP's for you:

1. The first IP it the `Emergency SSH Connection`. This points to the `host` server machine, and directly connects you to your VPS, even if it does not have a SSH working properly. This will use a `user name` allowed to connect to the host machine, where your VPS is installed. Therefore once it completes the connection, the `Host OS` will connect you to your VPS.
2. The second IP is the properly IP to your VPS properly, and this is the IP you should use to connect with `Win SCP`. Here you do not use the `Emergency SSH Connection` user name or password. As you may notice, the `Emergency SSH Connection` is restarting every time you reboot you VPS, so it indicate it could not be your VPS user name. To connect to the VPS, you must to use a valid and registered VPS user account/password, as your initially setup by your VPS provider `root` account and `password`.